# Container div height won't increase size according to the content

Tags: html, css

My container div height doesn't increase in size when the content div grows. In the code below, I want the div with class name `summary` to increase in size as div `house-address` grows. Any help will be much appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="summary shortS">
    <div class="house-address">
        <h2>booboo</h2>
        <p>hehe hehee hdhddgf jfhfjf lkjgkhgh kjgkjg itutiut mhvjhgjhfg nbcncnb nbcnbc</p>
    </div>
    <div class="house-price">
        <h4>$17272</h4>
        <p>Guide Price</p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.summary.shortS {
    display: block;
    height: 64px;
}

.house-address {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}

.house-price {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I had the similar problem [overflow: auto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) solved it

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `height: 64px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/cZsS5/

EDIT: as suggested, `min-height: 64px` is probably the desired style.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're defining an explicit `height` for the element (so long as it *also* has a class-name of `shorts`, which sets the element to that *specific* height regardless of its contents:

```
.summary.shortS {
    display: block;
    height: 64px;
}
```

Instead of `height` use `min-height` (if a `height of any kind must be defined to force visibility on the page, for example, even when empty):

```
.summary.shortS {
    display: block;
    min-height: 64px;
}
```

Otherwise simply remove the `height` declaration altogether.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zWzkr/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.summary.shortS {
display: block;
min-height: 64px;
height: auto;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Next time don't just post your code here, give some explanation first it will help future users with less experience understanding your answer.